# Insufficient output from SQL query

Tags: sql, output, northwind

I'm using the northwind db: http://dev.assets.neo4j.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/Northwind_diagram.jpg

I have to output all orders placed by CustomerID ALFKI with more than one unique product. I get the correct orders out, but I can't figure out why it's only printing one product name per order.

My query:

```
SELECT a.OrderID, p.ProductName
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN 'Order Details' a 
  ON (p.ProductID = a.ProductID) 
INNER JOIN Orders b 
  ON (a.OrderID = b.OrderID) 
WHERE (b.CustomerID = 'ALFKI') 
GROUP BY a.OrderID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.ProductID) > 1
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes around table or column names.  Only use them for string and date constants.  I can't figure out why you are not getting a syntax error.

Comment: The problem is GROUP BY, but I cannot figure out how else to check for COUNT greater than 1.

Comment: You need a subquery with the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the OrderIDs...Then you need your primary query to select the detail using the OrderIDs returned from the subquery.  Sorry I don't have a server available at moment to try it and I could not find a good online queryable copy of NW on the web.

Comment: @DavidTansey Thanks, that did the trick. Annoyed now that I didn't think of subquery to begin with, but, hey, live and learn. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem -- #SOreadytohelp

Comment: Were you actually running the original query on SQL Server or was the Northwind data copied to a MySQL database?

Comment: Could you please add the correct syntax for future reference as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to be part of a subquery, with your primary query selecting the detail using the list of `OrderID`s returned from the subquery as filter criteria.  Try the following syntax for T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    a.OrderID, 
    p.ProductName
FROM 
    Products p 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] a 
        ON (p.ProductID = a.ProductID) 
    INNER JOIN Orders b 
        ON (a.OrderID = b.OrderID) 
WHERE 
    a.OrderID IN 
    (
        SELECT a.OrderID
        FROM [Order Details] a 
        INNER JOIN Orders b 
            ON (a.OrderID = b.OrderID) 
        WHERE (b.CustomerID = 'ALFKI') 
        GROUP BY a.OrderID 
        HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT a.ProductID) > 1
    )
```

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted -- you will get two additional rep points for yourself!